# как записать тег внутри тега через javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
 <p id="secondImg"></p>

let secondImage=document.getElementById('secondImg');
secondImage=document.write(`<img src=${getImage}>`)
```

как через javascript писать тег внутри тега p хочу чтобы img тег была внутри тега p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

```js
let secondImage = document.getElementById('secondImg');
secondImage.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `<img src=${'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/ru/Img/favicon.ico'}>`)
```

```html
<p id="secondImg"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

JS

```js
document.querySelector('#secondImg').innerHTML = `<img>`;
```

```html
<p id="secondImg"></p>
```

JQuery

```js
$('#secondImg').html(`<img>`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="secondImg"></p>
```